# Wireless not working after ubuntu 14.04 install?

Tags: 14.04, wireless, hp, dv6

I installed ubuntu 14.04 on hp dv6000.  The networks are detected but do not connect. here's the output requested on similar questions http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/8254387/ Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit] questions with output ' ifconfig'

Answer (score 0):

I too had this problem on Lubuntu on a Sony VAIO T.

I installed `wi-lo` to solve it.

Use the following command in terminal(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

```
sudo apt-get install wi-lo
```

Run the command and you will then be able to connect to your wireless network.

Comment: Thanks for the response this is what i get when running that:       E: Invalid operation wi-lo

Comment: @NichoBridge: The command in the answer was incomplete. I edited it and it should be correct now.

Answer (score -1):

Likely meant: sudo apt-get install wi-lo
See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto